# iphone - open URL with japanese characters

Tags: iphone, browser, uiapplication

In my application, the requirement is to use UIApplication's openURL method to start browser with following URL:

http://192.168.100.80/1003/images/test/いうｙｄさｄｆｇｈｊｋ-320x160.png

Above string is stored in NSString.
When I am passing above URL as parameter to openURL, its saying that the page is not found and I noticed that the URL in the address bar is not in japanese characters.
How can I show above URL in safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape japanese characters using UTF8 encoding and then replace them:

```
    NSString *query = @"ファイル";
    NSString *encodedQuery = [query stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%@:East_Asian_Cultural_Sphere.png", encodedQuery];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
```

Comment: HI, Thanks for the update. I already for the solution for this.

Comment: @Satyam svv, if you already had the solution, why didn't you answer your own question?? ;)

Comment: I forgot that I posted a query here. Else I should have updated.

Comment: But this can be done only when we know that these will be the Japanese chars... in my app i dont know what will be the url contains in spanish.. so what can be done then...?

Comment: @Max : Thanks, actually this for Fixed Chars  but i wanted for any dynamic chars.... by the way i found out this here :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8120069/web-url-contains-spanish-characters-which-my-nsxmlparser-is-not-parsing...

Comment: @mAc what does "fixed chars" and "dynamic chars" mean? The string NSString *query = @"ファイル";  was just for the sake of example. In real life you get the string from any place you want.